# How to resize the image of the tree using sklearn tree and export_graph_viz within a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tree, jupyter-notebook, graphviz

I am using export_graph_viz to visualize a decision tree but the image spreads out of view in my Jupyter Notebook.

If this was a pyplot figure I would use the command plt.figure(figsize = (12,7)) to constrain the visualization.  But in this case I do not know how to proceed.

Below is a snapshot of my Jupyter Notebook and what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the visualized tree to a file and then show it with pyplot.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pydotplus
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import io

from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

dot_data = io.StringIO()

export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data, rounded=True, filled=True)

filename = "tree.png"
pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()).write_png(filename)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
img = mpimg.imread(filename)
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]